# How to set max size in Java TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap

I am building an Least Recently Used Cache using a TreeMap in Java. The reason I selected the TreeMap is because of the TreeMap.floorEntry (String) method.
I want to be able to specify a maximum size for my cache(TreeMap).
Then I want to use an LRU eviction mechanism, and therefore,
When the cache has reached the maximum size AND when there is a new record to be cached, 
I want the cache to add the new record, and remove the eldest entry.

Comment: There is no maximum size (except for the maximum size of a `Collection`, which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31 - 1`).

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for your comment. I have done something similar using a LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.
I would use ConcurrentSkipListMap(which has also floorEntry method) and implement my own little max size control.

This is what I would do:

```
int maxSize = 100;
ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, String> cache = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

// Check if max size is reached before inserting something in it. Make some room for new entry.
while (cache.size() >= maxSize) {
    cache.pollFirstEntry();
}
```

It's a bit hackish but should do the job.

Comment: How does it select the First Entry? Is it based on the key or it is the entry that was firstly added?

Comment: @Manos OK, I see. The code above doesn't do exactly what you hoped for. Can you tell me what you are storing as key and what will be the value in your map? Some example please? There's too little information to work on...

Comment: The key is a String and String.compareTo() can be used for comparison. To overcome the problem, if cache reaches maxSize, I am removing a random entry from the map, and then insert.